# parceljs not bundling axios properly

Tags: parceljs

parcel build command doesn't seem to add the Axios library properly, though it seems to be working fine in start script in npm (parcel src/index.html).

Link to the [issue](https://distracted-babbage-340f4c.netlify.app/github-profile/index.html) ..